# Why Anaconda does not recognize conda command?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I installed the latest version of Anaconda.
Now I want to install OpenCV within it. When I type:

```
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/anaconda opencv
```

I get this message error: "*conda is not recognized as internal command ...*" (sorry, I try to translate from French because my OS is in French)

The problem is that conda comes with Anaconda, so I wonder why lauching Anaconda and type the above command does not work ?

Comment: where are you running the command?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I open the shell of Anaconda and run them inside. Is it the right way ?

Comment: This has happened to me twice now.

If I forget to install opencv via Conda from Binstar using Sudo it results in a broken Anaconda distribution. Something happens in the step where Conda itself is upgrading/updating - in the end the Conda command is no longer recognized. 

If I check my /anaconda/bin/ folder, there is no command called conda

I guess I need to start using virtual environments so I stop breaking things...

Comment: In my case, reopening the shell works.

Comment: As google still finds this in the top list, in windows the correct solution is not any of the answers here but this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44515769/conda-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command

Answer (score 69):

### For Windows

Go to `Control Panel\System and Security\System\Advanced System Settings` then look for `Environment Variables`.

Your user variables should contain `Path=Path\to\Anaconda3\Scripts`.

You need to figure where your `Anaconda3` folder is (i.e. the path to this folder) . Mine was in `C:\Users`.

### For Linux

You need to add `conda` to `PATH`. To do so, type:

`export PATH=/path/to/anaconda3/bin:$PATH`.

Same thing, you need to figure the path to `anaconda3` folder (Usually, the path is stored in `$HOME`)

If you don't want to do this everytime you start a session, you can also add `conda` to `PATH` in your `.bashrc` file:

`echo 'export PATH=/path/to/anaconda3/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Re: the Windows path, looks to me like if you installed for all users, your conda installation (Anaconda, Miniconda, whatever) is in `C:\ProgramData`

Comment: I have Windows, I think I added the path (even I tried in both user variables and system variables) and ran cmd and it didn't recognized conda.

Comment: I then uninstalled Anaconda and installed it with the path added (not the recommended settings). There might have been a better way by simply changing the settings. Anyway...

Comment: Note: If you want to use DataSpell or PyCharm to create a Conda environment, you should not add Conda to the Windows environment variable because both IDEs will automatically detect it.

Comment: In my case it was in C:\ProgramData\anaconda3 and insteed _conda.exe was installed _conda.exe. I've copied and renamed _conda.exe to conda.exe. There are both files are present in anaconda3 folder

Answer (score 44):

I had a similar problem. I searched `conda.exe` and I found it on Scripts folder. So, In Anaconda3 you need to add two variables to `PATH`. The first is `Anaconda_folder_path` and the second is `Anaconda_folder_path\Scripts`

Comment: By 'Anacond_folder_path' I mean the folder you installed Anaconda.

Answer (score 7):

When you install anaconda on windows now, it doesn't automatically add Python or Conda to your path so you have to add it yourself.

If you don’t know where your conda and/or python is, you type the following commands into your anaconda prompt

[image]

Next, you can add **Python and Conda** to your path by using the setx command in your command prompt.
[image]

Next close that command prompt and open a new one. Congrats you can now use conda and python

Source: https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/install-python-on-windows-anaconda-c63c7c3d1444

Comment: `SETX PATH` is an interesting solution. However, `where` doesn't always show the python exe of anaconda.

Comment: The command `where` won't work, if the path to the file wasn't added to `%PATH%`. So in this case it won't show, where it is.

Answer (score 4):

You probably need to update your `PATH` variable to include where you have installed Anaconda.

See https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/41 for a similar issue.

Comment: I just did that (I am running Windows 7) but still the problem is there. Thank you for trying.

Comment: Yes, I did that as the administrator

Comment: Thx a lot. I did what it said in the link and conda works just fine!

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and I did something like the below mentioned steps with my Path environment variable to fix the problem

> 1. Located where my Anaconda3 was installed. I run Windows 7. Mine is located at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3.
> 2. Open **Control Panel - System - Advanced System Settings**, under Advanced tab click on Environment Variables.
> 3. Under **System Variables, located "Path"** add the following: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\;

**Save and open new terminal. 
type in "conda". It worked for me.**

Hope these steps help

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you forget to export PATH, anaconda/bin must be added in your $PATH. (Linux, OSX common problem). On Windows make sure you run install and commands as administrator.

Comment: I am running Windows 7, I did not find bin folder for Anaconda. Is there an equivalent folder under Windows or is it the same ?

Comment: There are other users on my computer, but when I installed Anaconda, I am the only user allowed to use it, so I think I am its administrator

Comment: check the install path maybe is /Users... and not in default C:\anaconda. Also scripts must be added to path.

Comment: Yes, you are right , installation path is `C:\users\myname\AppData\...` Must i uninstall it and reinstall it so that the path will be `C:\Anaconda ...` ?

Comment: no, just you add this path to your path environment, also scripts path (scripts is a folder inside anaconda root ).

Comment: yes, i did that already. But after the comment under my question directly, I run the command on CMD not within Anaconda shell. It seems the right place to run it. Now I just get an other error saying it is not able to connect to ... (i think it is because of the firewall)

Answer (score 3):

Same problem with Anaconda running on Ubuntu 15.10.  I closed the terminal and opened a new window and it worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

Faced the same problem running on Windows 10 and using the Windows cmd.

Solved it by running the following command in the Anaconda Prompt which comes with Anaconda3 (as administrator):

```
conda install -c menpo opencv3=3.1.0
```

Command found on the official website: https://anaconda.org/menpo/opencv3

Comment: It's a shane anaconda.org doesn't mention the `Anaconda Prompt` program because searching for `conda` only turns up `.conda\` and `.condarc`  - lost 90 minutes of my life because of this.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the file path using (for anaconda3)...

```
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

Then check whether it worked with...

```
conda --version
```

This worked for me when 'conda' was returning 'command not found'.

Answer (score 2):

Try restarting the terminal, I had the same issue, worked after restarting the terminal.

Comment: This works if you had the terminal opened before changing the `Path` variable.

Answer (score 1):

If this problem persists, you may want to check all path values in the PATH variable (under `Control Panel\System and Security\System\Advanced System Settings`). It might be that some other path is invalid or contains an illegal character.

Today, I had the same problem and found a double quote in a different path value in the PATH variable. All paths after that (including a fresly installed conda) were not usable. Removing the double quote solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 10, I went to the folder where Anaconda is stored. In my case it is in \Anaconda3 folder as a shortcut to open a command prompt window, called "Anaconda Prompt". Open that and execute the command [t](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiCHe.jpg)here.

Answer (score 1):

Got same issue and it turns out that besides setting PATH variable, I also should not close some cmd window poped up during installation. Re-installation would work

Answer (score 1):

**It's not recommended to add conda.exe path directly into the System Environment Variables** at stated by anaconda installer :

[image]

**For Windows Users**, Open Conda Prompt Shortcut and ***change the Target into the Correct Address*** :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As other users said, the best way for Windows users is to set the global environment variable.

I install the Miniconda3 for MXNet.

Before I do something, only Anaconda Prompt works for `conda`.

After setting the global environment variable, The CMD and Git Bash work.
But in some IDEs like RStudio, the nested Git Bash doesn't work.

After restarting my computer, the Git Bash in the RStudio works for `conda`.

I hope these tests helps for you.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 11 x64, default is

```
"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe"
```

CMD, run, `systempropertiesadvanced` , add to `PATH` variable.

[image]

[image]