# Windows 10 conda is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

Tried to

`conda install -c conda-forge requests-futures=0.9.7`

but failed with

`conda is not recognized as an internal or external command`,

`C:\Users\user_name\Anaconda3\Scripts` has been set for `Path` in `environment variables` under both `user` and `System variables`.

I installed `Python 3.5` as well and it is on `Path`, I am using `Win10 X64`.

How to fix the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Anaconda does not recognize conda command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28612500/why-anaconda-does-not-recognize-conda-command)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a similar question asked here before, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28612500/why-anaconda-does-not-recognize-conda-command) may be it will help you.

To make sure that conda package is installed correctly, check if conda package files  , i.e `conda` `conda-env` `conda-env-script` `conda-script` `conda-server` `conda-server-script` etc are present in Anaconda3\Scripts folder.

Comment: Also Check if conda files are present in Anaconda3\Scripts folder.

Comment: what do you mean by `conda` files?

Comment: `conda` package files , i.e `conda` `conda-env` `conda-env-script` `conda-script` `conda-server` `conda-server-script`
 Just to make sure that conda package is installed correctly

Comment: missing `conda`, `conda-env`, `conda-env-script`, `conda-script`, what should I do? I was updating `anaconda3` to the latest version using `conda update`.

Comment: You can add these files from Anaconda3\pkgs conda-4.3.14-py36_1.tar.bz2 (version can be different). add each file in specified folders and then try.

Comment: happy to help :)

Comment: but there is another issue when trying `conda install`, i.e. `AttributeError: module 'conda.cli' has no attribute 'main' `. I copied `conda-script` from `conda-4.3.21-py35_0` to `C:\Users\user_name\Anaconda3\Scripts`.

Comment: have you also include the Lib , etc and info  files from `conda-4.3.21-py35_0` ?

Comment: `conda-4.3.21-py35_0\Lib\site-packages`? with folder `conda` and `conda_env` and file `conda-4.3.21-py3.5.egg-info`

Answer (score 5):

When you install anaconda on windows now, it doesn't automatically add Python or Conda to your path.

If you don’t know where your conda and/or python is, you type the following commands into your anaconda prompt

[image]

Next, you can add **Python and Conda** to your path by using the setx command in your command prompt.
[image]

Next close that command prompt and open a new one. Congrats you can now use conda and python

Source: https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/install-python-on-windows-anaconda-c63c7c3d1444

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem when using cmd.

From your Command prompt 'C:\Users\zkdur\anaconda3\Scripts

**Now try**

`conda init --help`

`conda init --verbose`  after that restart your command prompt and `conda` will be working.

Answer (score 0):

After installing Anaconda on windows 10, you can use Anaconda prompt from start menu to activate a conda enabled terminal window.

Answer (score -3):

Just Check Both the options while installing Anaconda.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WogNs.jpg)