conda create --name opencv-env conda 'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
I was following the video on Install OpenCV on Windows. After installing Anaconda. They tell you to open CMD and type "conda create --name opencv-env"
But I was getting this error "'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command" There was a lot of other ways people where going about this issue. Looks as if you check the box when installing "Add Anaconda3 to my PATH Env" That is all you need to do to fix it. As of today 11/28/2024 on Windows 11 Home Version 23H2
I was trying to install OpenCV to Anaconda using the CMD. But got a error. After uninstalling and checking the Add Anaconda3 to my PATH Evn That was the way to fix the issue.

or perhaps more specifically https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44488349/windows-10-conda-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

"the video", what video

The documentation suggests:

Should I add Anaconda to the Windows PATH?
When installing Anaconda, Anaconda recommends that you do not add Anaconda to the Windows PATH because this can interfere with other software. Instead, open Anaconda with the Start Menu and select Anaconda Prompt, or use Anaconda Navigator (Start Menu - Anaconda Navigator).

