# Anaconda : Update conda failed because permission error

Tags: python, anaconda, windows-7-x64, conda

I'm using Anaconda version 5.1 on Windows 7 (64bit).

I have tried to update conda from 4.4.10-py36_0 to 4.4.11-py36_0 but cannot and got error message

> (base) C:\Windows\system32>conda update -n base conda Solving
>   environment: done
>
> ### Package Plan
>
> environment location: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
>
> added / updated specs:
>       - conda
>
> The following packages will be downloaded:
>
> ```
> package                    |            build
> ---------------------------|-----------------
> conda-4.4.11               |           py36_0         955 KB
> ```
>
> The following packages will be UPDATED:
>
> ```
> conda: 4.4.10-py36_0 --> 4.4.11-py36_0
> ```
>
> Proceed ([y]/n)? y
>
> Downloading and Extracting Packages conda 4.4.11:
>
> ################################################### | 100% Preparing transaction: done Verifying transaction: done Executing
>
> transaction: failed ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(481): An error
>   occurred while uninstalling packag e 'defaults::conda-4.4.10-py36_0'.
>   PermissionError(13, 'The process cannot access the file because it is
>   being used  by another process') Attempting to roll back.
>
> Rolling back transaction: done
>
> PermissionError(13, 'The process cannot access the file because it is
>   being used  by another process')

I uninstalled and re-installed it but got the same issue.

Comment: I found the solution for this issue here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44515769/conda-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command

Answer (score -1):

Run the command prompt using the "Command Prompt (Admin)" option from the power users menu, push both Windows key - X at same time.