# Anaconda install fails. Install vscode fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, installation, anaconda

I cannot install 64-bit Anaconda 3 on Windows 10. It says the install is complete but when I proceed to install VSCode, it fails. It says to check my internet connection and to look in the log file. But my internet connection is fine and there is no log file. I am running the install with Windows Defender turned off.

When I look at the start menu, none of the components except for Anaconda Prompt, are there. I would like to have Spyder and Jupyter, for example, but they are not there.

If I install the 32-bit version, it works fine. But I need the 64-bit version

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue here. For easy VS code installation with 64-bit anaconda version, you can follow this way:

Install ananconda navigator typing this on shell:

```
 conda install -c anaconda anaconda-navigator
```

Open anaconda navigator:

```
anaconda-navigator
```

It opens a GUI anaconda interface. You can install VS Code from here, only click *Install*:
[image]

It stays *Installing dependencies* for me all the time, but after reboot, appears installed and works properly.

Hope it helps. It would be interesting to know how to obtain this with conda commands avoiding navigator installation.

Comment: I get: "'conda' is not a recognized program or external command..." Any further suggestions?

Comment: I use Ubuntu, not Windows, but maybe you haven't added Anaconda to your PATH variable . Check these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44515769/conda-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command).

Comment: I put conda.exe in my path and I get the error "Unable to create process using 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\pkgs\conda-4.5.4-py36_0\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\pkgs\conda-4.5.4-py36_0\Scripts\conda-script.py" install x'

Answer (score -1):

I simply close the navigator and open Anaconda Navigator as `Run as administrator`
and my problem solved.