# The term 'conda' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, anaconda, conda

I have installed **Anaconda 2019.03 for Windows Installer** in Windows 10.
When typing anything which starts with `conda` on Powershell getting error:

> conda : The term 'conda' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
>   path is correct and try again.

I have tried below solutions, which did not solved the problem:

- Added path as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51996934/2576748)
- As shown [here](https://appuals.com/fix-conda-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-batch-file/), tried Method 1 and when opening **Anaconda Prompt** it says:

> 'C:\Users\user-name\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

- Looked at above direction, there is not `activate.bat` file there.
- Uninstall and install as shown on [metod 2](https://appuals.com/fix-conda-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-batch-file/), also did not changed anything.
- Opened **Anaconda Powershell Prompt** in addition to 'conda' is not recognized also getting below error:

> & : The term 'C:\Users\user-name\Anaconda3\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
>   path is correct and try again.

- Actually, Path `C:\Users\user-name\Anaconda3\shell` do not exists when I have looked.

Additional information listed:

- I have installed **MySQL** on my PC
- `C:\Users\user-name\Anaconda3\envs` is empty
- **Avira** antivirus installed
- **Python 3.7.3** installed before **Anaconda**

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Keep in mind that if you update the path environment variable, that change is not automatically propagated to existing open PowerShell consoles.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I did not change evns' path.

Comment: @isifzade In the "Added path as shown here" part you put in, you should have modified your Path variable. Once you have changed this, you will need to close and open all your powershell sessions. Can we assume that you Windows user name is `user-name` or have you actually replaced it with your proper username? (you can run `whoami` on either CMD or powershell to find out your username)

Comment: @Shadowzee I have on purpose replaced my original user name with user-name to post a question here. In reality I have used the original user name of PC.

Comment: @isifzade I can't help much more. I found this question via the powershell tag and if the command isn't present, then its either not installed correctly or the path hasn't been added into the environment variables properly. Can you confirm that the directory you added into the environment variables contains the executable "conda"? You might have linked the wrong folder (The linked question says to link Scripts not Shell)

Comment: @Shadowzee I did not added the path of shell, It is an error which Powershell prompted. I have added these two into  Environment Variables: C:\Users\user-name\Anaconda3\Scripts, C:\Users\user-name\Anaconda3

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I have just understand what you mean. Even closing the Powershell and restarting PC did not helped.

Answer (score 51):

Found an awesome medium post that laid this out cleanly:

1. Install latest Anaconda + PowerShell
2. Open Anaconda prompt, and type "conda init powershell"
3. Open PowerShell and it should work.

Basically creates a file at "%userprofile%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1" that PowerShell will execute every time it initiates, connecting it to PowerShell.

**Source:**
https://hackf5.medium.com/how-to-enable-anaconda-in-powershell-7-on-windows-394ba62c3f9c

Comment: Doing just `conda init powershell` fixed it for me, thanks :)

Comment: executing from an elevated CMD "conda init powershell" fixed it for me thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you use the default "old" PowerShell 5, check whether the `profile.ps1` in `C:\Users\USER\Documents\WindowsPowerShell` contains:

```
#region conda initialize
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
(& "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe" "shell.powershell" "hook") | Out-String | Invoke-Expression
#endregion
```

[image]

If you have a message that the profile.ps1 cannot be executed, solve that problem with `set-executionpolicy remotesigned` (but: insecure, thus, not recommended!), see:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

Installieren Sie die neueste PowerShell für neue Funktionen und Verbesserungen! https://aka.ms/PSWindows

. : Die Datei "C:\Users\USER\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1" kann nicht geladen werden, da die Ausführung
von Skripts auf diesem System deaktiviert ist. Weitere Informationen finden Sie unter "about_Execution_Policies"
(https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170).
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:3
+ . 'C:\Users\USER\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1'
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : Sicherheitsfehler: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> set-executionpolicy remotesigned

Ausführungsrichtlinie ändern
Die Ausführungsrichtlinie trägt zum Schutz vor nicht vertrauenswürdigen Skripts bei. Wenn Sie die Ausführungsrichtlinie
 ändern, sind Sie möglicherweise den im Hilfethema "about_Execution_Policies" unter
"https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170" beschriebenen Sicherheitsrisiken ausgesetzt. Möchten Sie die
Ausführungsrichtlinie ändern?
[J] Ja  [A] Ja, alle  [N] Nein  [K] Nein, keine  [H] Anhalten  [?] Hilfe (Standard ist "N"): j
```

[image]

After entering `j`, restart PowerShell. You will see the `profile.ps1` in action:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

Installieren Sie die neueste PowerShell für neue Funktionen und Verbesserungen! https://aka.ms/PSWindows

Das Laden von persönlichen und Systemprofilen dauerte 1400 ms.
(base) PS C:\Users\USER>
```

[image]

In short, try to make it possible that the "profile.ps1" gets loaded. In my case, I did not need this trick anymore since I [installed PowerShell 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/migrating-from-windows-powershell-51-to-powershell-7?view=powershell-7.2) which is allowed to load the `profile.ps1` by default. You might also just open the old PowerShell 5 from Visual Studio Code instead and change the settings so that `conda init` runs at the start, see [How to add anaconda powershell to vscode?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64687777/11154841).

Its `profile.ps1` had the same content, you find it in `C:\Users\USER\Documents\PowerShell\profile.ps1`.

When I start PowerShell 7, `conda init` runs automatically, no insecure tricks needed. Therefore, just install PowerShell 7 in parallel (do not remove the old PowerShell 5!) and use the new version instead.