# How to add anaconda powershell to vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, anaconda

I'm trying to add anaconda prompt to start up instead of powershell to avoid having to add python to env variables.

```
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
    <args>
]
```

I tried putting them into single line, splitting them "-Foo Goo" as well as "-Foo","Goo". Each version leads to either error or simply ignoring the "-Command" parameter (the lines simply get pasted, but not executed).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up using this (although it has tendency to break).

```js
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
    "-ExecutionPolicy"
    , "ByPass" 
    , "-NoExit"
    , "-Command"
    , "& 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\shell\\condabin\\conda-hook.ps1' ; conda activate 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3'"
],
```

Answer (score 22):

First of all, I I'd like to give a hint for everyone that uses PowerShell to use the [new one](https://github.com/powershell/powershell).

So, with the Anaconda ready to go (and it been equal or greater than 4.6 - use `conda --version`) run in sequence (from base environment in cwd terminal):

```
conda update conda
conda init
```

This will update your conda root environment and the init will setup all you need to run it on both cwd and powershell.

After this, you can start any powershell (inside vscode or not) and it will be conda ready.

Look at [this article](https://www.scivision.dev/conda-powershell-python/) for further information.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Simple and sweet!

Comment: This worked! I'm on windows 10, only extra things I had to do was select Command Prompt as my terminal.

Comment: Thanks! This really helped me a lot.

Comment: I think this "broke" my Powershell. Got a "profile.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is
disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170."

Comment: @JesseW.Collins try to run `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` on your powershel... this issue is because your powershell is not allowed to run scripts. Do it as administrator (open the powershell as admin). PS: This info is in the article.

Comment: Thank you!!!! that conda init saved me. I've been trying all day to work and this finally solved for me.

Comment: This worked for me but only with the new PowerShell. In addition, ```conda init``` is all that is needed.  Which updated the PowerShell profile.

Answer (score 11):

Thanks Zerg! Your answer worked for me but I also got a warning message to say that this approach has been depreciated. After some googling I got this working by adding a new terminal [profile](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal) to settings.json.

```
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "PowerShell (Anaconda)": {
          "source": "PowerShell",
          "args": [
            "-ExecutionPolicy"
            , "ByPass" 
            , "-NoExit"
            , "-Command"
            , "& 'C:\\Users\\<username>\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\shell\\condabin\\conda-hook.ps1' ; conda activate 'C:\\Users\\<username>\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3'"
        ]
        }
    },
```

Then changing the default profile:

```
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell (Anaconda)",
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I was looking for it. However, I have a warning when changing the default profile on the settings.json. I used the + icon next to the command window with the dropdown. Now powershell (anaconda) appear as an option. I chose it as the default profile.

Comment: This did the trick!  Thanks =D.  As an added note, you can append a `; conda activate your_env_here` to get it to start a prompt with your specific environment.  Also, might be handy to have `"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": false` set.

Answer (score 3):

From the VSCode Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P), select

```
Terminal: Select default shell
```

and then pick **PowerShell**.

Then from the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P), select

```
Python: Select Interpreter
```

and pick one of the conda environments. When you now open a new terminal VSCode starts PowerShell and activates the selected environment. This is exactly what the Anaconda-Prompt does. However, you should not set a PYTHONPATH in the environment in combination with an Anaconda install. Conda activation is all you need. It not only adds the selected interpreter to the PATH, but the required libraries too.

Answer (score 2):

I just installed PowerShell 7, and since I had anaconda installed before, this seems to add the starting command to the `profile.ps1` automatically.

The `profile.ps1` in `C:\Users\USER\Documents\PowerShell` (this is version 7, directory `WindowsPowerShell` would be the old version 5) contains:

```
#region conda initialize
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
(& "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe" "shell.powershell" "hook") | Out-String | Invoke-Expression
#endregion
```

[image]

With these automatic settings at the start of PowerShell 7, adding PowerShell 7 as a new terminal type to vsccode solved it.

This is how to add PowerShell 7 to the dropdown menu:

Enter `Ctrl+Shift+P`, open `settings.json` for the User, and add

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "PowerShell7": {
          "path": "C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7\\pwsh.exe",
          "args": ["-NoProfile",
          "-noexit",
          "-file",
          "C:\\Users\\USER\\Documents\\PowerShell\\profile.ps1"]
        }
      },
      "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell7"
}
```

Then in the `settings.json`, press `Ctrl+s` and restart (!) vscode. You will see PowerShell7 as the new default terminal in the dropdown of terminal types:

[image]