# "Exit code: 1" in anaconda navigator after reinstalling anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, exit, navigator

After reinstalling Anaconda, I get the error message "Exit code: 1" when I start apps using the Anaconda Navigator. e.g. "jupyter notebook" or "CMD.exe"

[image: Exit code: 1]

When I use the CMD (base) via Env. or start from the windows start bar, it works.
Jupyter also runs when I start it directly from the start bar.

[image: This works]

I only get the error message in the Anaconda navigator.
I uninstalled Visual Studio. Still does not work.

Comment: Facing similar issue inPython 3.9 • 64-Bit Graphical Installer , tried uninstall/ removed all the temporary files. still facing the similar issue

Comment: I also installed it several times.

I also tried to delete all temporary files.

I think it's a problem in the anaconda navigator. The anaconda version of
j-notebook and CMD basically work. (e.g. start bar)

Comment: Did you find anything? @RP.

Answer (score 4):

Spent a few hours on this :

You need to run this in command prompt --> `conda install ipykernel --update-deps --force-reinstall`

There are 2 Errors popped for me for you it may be something else:

1. Wrong System-path[in my case -->  C`:/Windows/System32` and `C:/Windows/System`] PATH in Env. variables
2. If you get chcp error in command prompt then add [ Value : `chcp 1252` Name : `Autorun` ] for `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` in regedit.

Comment: Not to be pedantic but the user needs to run as adminstrator for this to work properly but it in my opinion is the best/easiest solution, so +1

Answer (score 4):

Go to Environment Variables under System variables.

Under PATH , click Edit and add NEW:

C:\Windows\System32

Save and exit.

All Credit to : Original solution posted under @BAIZ1D
https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/12735

Answer (score 2):

This issue arises in Windows when you reinstall the Anaconda, Miniconda, or even Miniforge. Because some registry keys remain after the first installation, you need to wipe them from Windows Registry after uninstallation and then reinstall the Anaconda.

The suspected key in your situation is the `AutoRun` that is added to the `"HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor"`; thus, just remove the key from the registry after uninstallation, and then reinstall:

```
C:\Windows\System32\reg.exe DELETE "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun /f
```

Comment: If you can't get around the command line, use the registry editor as mentioned in the link below
https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/12735.


1. Registry editor (regedit) on start menu and go to
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor

2. delete autorun

| this fixed both cmd.exe and anaconda navigator launching

Answer (score 0):

After lot of fiddling around, I found out a solution for the issue in local machine. Somehow system path variables were deleted. I added following entries for system path variables and reinstalled anaconda and everything works fine! C:\Windows\System32;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;

Refer : ['chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. on a Windows PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142058/chcp-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error.

I added below under Environment Variables ,

C:/Windows/System32
C:/Python310 (Python installed here in my case)

Also I checked the Registry and I don't find any Autorun which is recommended to delete.

It didn't worked for me after adding the above. Then I restarted the machine it worked without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Add C:/Windows/System32 and C:/Windows/System as PATH in Environment variables
and delete other entries of Anaconda applications (I had pycharm deleted) from env. variables. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing with the same problem too..

I tried to uninstall and reinstall the Anaconda but it was a waste of time. I just did these steps and I solve the problem!:

Go to Environment Variables under System variables.
Click to "Advanced".
Under "Path", click "Edit" and add "New":

C:\Windows\System32

Save and exit.

Credit to : Original solution posted under @BAIZ1D

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue after I tried to reinstall the Anaconda Navigator.
Many suggested deleting the Autorun file or editing the value but I did not have "autorun"  files ... finally noticed that I'm missing a file under Command Processor and adding the file as well as adding the path fixed the error `"Exit Code: 1"`.
Having said that: This solution is specifically for those who ***CAN NOT*** find THE "`Command Processor`" Or can not delete the autorun and/or don't have an autorun.

1- Go to the registry editor
(run>regedit)

***`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor`***

looks for "`PathCompletionChar`" and put the same value as "`CompletionChar`" `REG_DOWRD`.
If you missing the file then Create a new REG_DWORD and name it "PathCompletionChar" and put the same value as "`CompletionChar`".
In my case, it was 40.

[image]

2- Adding C:\Windows\System32 as PATH to the Environment Variables.

[image]

Control panel > system > Advanced System settings > Environment Variables >New > add `PATH` as name and `C:\Windows\System32` as value
save and close it. **Make sure to restart the computer.**
I hope that help.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to the latest powershell solved the problem for me.  I uninstalled Anaconda, then installed the latest powershell from the microsoft store, then reinstalled anaconda.
Reference: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56314710/the-term-conda-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet)

Answer (score 0):

**"Exit Code: 1" in Anaconda Navigator apps launch & command prompts**

I had the same error in *Anaconda Navigator* and *cmd.exe* command prompt would also crash with the same Exit Code: 1. The solution to the command prompt error also fixed my Anaconda app launch problem. No reinstall required.

Enter the following command in PowerShell:

```
C:\Windows\System32\reg.exe DELETE "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun /f
```

[Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66836989/8116942) for command prompt error by @crisprog.