# "is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Tags: anaconda, prompt

I've installed anaconda for python 2.7 and I get a message that indicates that the directory is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. What does this mean and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: You're not supposed to execute directories. Try executing a program instead.

Comment: you need to give more information. But your question rings a bell: see a similar issue reported some time ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44515769/conda-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command

Comment: I get the mentioned message when I open the anaconda prompt tho. The link you've provided deals with command prompt.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you share an excerpt from your terminal or a capture of the screen with the error?