# 'Conda' Not Recognized Command; Also Cannot Find "Conda" with "Where Conda" command

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, conda

I am a complete beginner and I am trying to learn to code. I just installed Python, PyCharm and Anaconda.

The `conda` command is not being recognized.

I tried searching `where conda` but neither `where conda` nor `where python` are recognized in the Anaconda cmd prompt.

I also tried changing the path in the environmental variables of Windows but it did not help (though again, I am a beginner, maybe I did it wrong).

The error message is:

> 'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

When typing `where conda` the error message is:

```
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
```

Comment: What was the path that you added?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Conda' is not recognized as internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44515769/conda-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command)