# Running scrapy spider from script results in error ImportError: No module named scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, import, scrapy

I've installed scrapy and created a spider that works when run from the command line with the command scrapy crawl getBUCPower. My issue is that I need to run the spider from another script when something specific happens. I have a separate python script thats just a test for now, but it tries to run the spider by the line:

```
execfile("../scrapy/data_spider/data_spider/spiders/getBUCPower.py")
```

When I run that script, I immediately get the error:

> File "getBUCPower.py", line 2, in 
>   import scrapy
>   ImportError: No module named scrapy

I have scrapy installed correctly as it work when I run the scrapy crawl command so I am unaware of what the issue is right now.

Here is my spider

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader

class DataSpider(Spider):
#sets the name of the spider
name = 'getBUCPower'
#sets the pipeline the spider should use
custom_settings = {
    'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
        'data_spider.pipelines.CsvPipeline': 300
    }
}
#sets the url the spider should crawl
allowed_domains = [ip]
start_urls = [ipHTTP]


def parse(self, response):
    #sets the information the sipder should grab
    BUCPower = response.xpath('//*[@id="mmwpaTxPower"]/text()').extract_first()
    #returns the information
    yield{"BUCPower" : BUCPower}

process = CrawlerProcess(settings={
'FEED_FORMAT': 'json',
'FEED_URI': 'items.json'
})

process.crawl(DataSpider)
process.start()
```

I currently have scrapy 1.6 and am using Python 2.7.16

The expected result is to run the spider from another script, but instead it has an issue importing scrapy.

Comment: How are you running the python script that contains `execfile()`?  What version of Python is used?

Comment: currently i am just running it from command line by "python callGetBucPower.py" and i am using 2.7.16

Comment: What output do you get from `python --version`?  What is your `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: Python 2.7.16 :: Anaconda, Inc.
im not sure how to find my PYTHONPATH

Comment: You're using Anaconda?  How did you install scrapy?

Comment: is this how you get the path?
C:\Users\astanecek>python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
['', 'C:\\Users\\astanecek\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda2\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Users\\astanecek\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda2\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\astanecek\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda2\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\astanecek\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda2\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Users\\astanecek\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda2\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Users\\astanecek\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda2', 'C:\\Users\\astanecek\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages

Comment: pip install scrapy

Comment: I'm not sure pip is the right way to install packages for use with Anaconda.

Comment: how should i go about installing it?

Comment: I believe the command is `conda` instead of `pip`.

Comment: conda is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51996934/4949165

Answer (score 0):

run anaconda prompt as administrator and then simply install scrapy by command

```
pip install scrapy
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the following code in anaconda/miniconda prompt:

```
conda install scrapy
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing *protego* package solved the issue for me.

`conda install protego`
or
`pip install protego`