# Trouble importing packages in python

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I had to reinstall Anaconda and Python in my computer. After that I have started getting troubles. Let me describe what are happening.

I installed Anaconda in Program Files. When I try accessing anaconda from start menu, I am getting the  error.

**Navigator Error**

An unexpected error occurred on Navigator start-up

After that tried accessing Jupyter from Anaconda Prompt. Got the following error.

`'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Installed some packages from Anaconda Prompt and checked that they can be imported inside python from the shell.

[image: Anaconda Prompt]

After that from start menu I launched jupyter notebook. Inside Jupyter I again failed to import packages that I was able to access from Python prompt.

[image: Jupyterlab Notebook]
I am confused and lost. Would appreciate any help. I have done multiple install/uninstall.

Comment: Where is the following error?

Comment: It says in the warnings that your `jupyter` is not added to path. Can you install a vanilla python version and go about installing libraries as and when you need?

Comment: @YagizcanDegirmenci - I made some changes. Does it now make sense?

Comment: @Ketan - my want to create a project report. Hence being able to do things from ```jupyter``` helps. Keeping that in mind, can you please tell me steps I should take? Uninstall everything? Then install Python. Then do ```pip install jupyter```?

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: The Python installation you invoke in the first screenshot isn't related to Anaconda/Conda, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Did you just update anything?

Try to import the same thing in Spyder or other python console. Check if it is giving detailed traceback for the issue.

Try updating conda, anaconda , anaconda-navigator from anaconda prompt.

Comment: This is what happens when I try Spyder. ```import yfinance
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-d716011b5664>", line 1, in <module>
    import yfinance

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yfinance'```

Comment: Did u tried updating conda and anaconda...make sure that you have added environment variables

Comment: This is new install. So should be up to date. On the top of that I tried doing, if I do ```conda list``` in command prompt, i get ```'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file```

Comment: You need to add path variables to your pc..search online you will get it. Moreover read this answer. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44515769/conda-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command