# How can I activate a Conda environment from PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, anaconda, windows-10

Version [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)) 4.8.3

What I cannot do: 
I can't **activate** any environment from PowerShell.
`conda activate base`

What I can do:

`conda env list`
`conda create -n xxx` `conda remove -n xxx`

I have tried many solutions, but they turned out to be useless:

1. `conda init powershell` 
   `restart powershell`
   `conda activate`
2. `conda update -n base conda` and redo 1
3. `conda install -n root -c pscondaenvs pscondaenvs`  
   `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` 
   Run `activate base`

[The result of running `conda activate`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIfmb.png)

Comment: Were you running Powershell with elevated/admin permissions when you tried `conda init` ? There were no errors?

Comment: Yeah, I tried both admin and non-admin powershell, and the result turns out the same. " no change <path of some .exe's and .bat's>" @AMC

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64149680/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 101):

You don't need administrator permissions.

Once you install Anaconda or Miniconda on Windows, open a `Anaconda PowerShell Prompt` from Start Menu.

Or, *if* you don't see it there, then assuming you have installed
miniconda3 at path C:\miniconda3\4.9.2, do:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoExit -Command "& 'C:\miniconda3\4.9.2\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1' ; conda activate 'C:\miniconda3\4.9.2' "
```

Now try:

```
conda init powershell
```

and reopen PowerShell.

**Additional note:** By default, conda will autoactivate itself, when we open terminal. If you prefer not, then disable auto-activation with:

```
conda config --set auto_activate_base false
```

Comment: Solution looked promising, but actually it is not bypassing the restriction and after restart (with full modificatoin of files by conda) it is still not working properly.

On restart the same
```\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.     
At line:1 char:3```
(referencing the automatically created ps script)

Comment: In this case you simply need to [unblock the file named `profile.ps1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-7.1#example-7--unblock-a-script-to-run-it-without-changing-the-execution-policy): `Unblock-File -Path .\profile.ps1` (replace relative path with full path) See [Unblock-File cmdlet doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/unblock-file)

Comment: Does that work on Powershell 7? (Doesn't seem to on my machine but it may be from another cause).

Comment: This solution worked, but now I deleted the anaconda environment and I don't know how to remove the automatic activation at each startup.

Comment: The tip of "disable auto-activation" is really helpful. If conda auto-activates every time, I can't use the Python that is directly installed on my machine.

Answer (score 84):

Open a *Anaconda PowerShell Prompt* from Start Menu.
Now try:

```
conda init powershell
```

Now restart PowerShell. If you find some error like this in PowerShell:

> \WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170. At line:1 char:3

Then change the execution policy. Type this code to PowerShell:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

To find out more about execution policy, you can visit [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.1).

Comment: without admin priviliges: `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser`

Comment: This is the best answer with the comment from @Winand. Solved my headaches with VS Code's integrated terminal.

Answer (score 30):

Here is my **easier** solution which works with Anaconda, [Miniconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)), and even Miniforge:

1. Open PowerShell and browse to `condabin` folder in your Conda installation directory, for example: `C:\Users\<username>\anaconda3\condabin`
2. Run `./conda init powershell` in that folder, and reopen the PowerShell.
3. **Please note:** If you encountered `ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system`, simply run the PowerShell as Administrator and enter the following: `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`
4. Restart the PowerShell and enjoy!

Comment: Wow, this worked for me after trying multiple things

Comment: This is the best and the simplest answer on this matter. I have miniconda3 installed on my machine. It worked like a charm. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 10):

When you use Anaconda or Miniconda, type in Anacondaprompt:

```
conda init powershell
```

Answer (score 5):

In order to activate Conda in PowerShell, I just executed this command:

```
C:\Users\<username>\anaconda3\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1
```

Then I could see all environments without needing to restart PowerShell.

```
conda env list
conda activate base
```

So you need to basically just run the `conda-hook.ps1` script.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem. The trick is to make sure that the environment is included in the PATH variable of Windows PowerShell. To view the PATH variables enter the following in the PowerShell:

```
$env:Path.split(';')
```

If the environment you desire doesn't show up in the output list, as in

.....
.....
..../envs/yourEnv/...
.....

Run the following command in [cmd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe):

```
conda init powershell
```

Then restart _Anaconda PowerShell, and
then:

```
conda activate yourEnv
```

Hopefully, now the Conda prompt should now show your desired environment.

Answer (score 3):

To solve the problem without changing the security policy on PowerShell, **you need to be on PowerShell 7**. PowerShell 7 will let you use a *\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1* file as the startup script with the default (restricted) security policy settings. Windows PowerShell is by default (on Windows 10 at 14-08-2022) version 5.x.

Check your PowerShell version with

```
$PSVersionTable
```

If you're still on PowerShell 5, install PowerShell from the windows store. This will install PowerShell 7 alongside PowerShell 5. It will probably be called *PowerShell* instead of *Windows PowerShell*. Or if you're not allowed to use the windows store, ask IT to install it for you. Check the version again in the new PowerShell.

After this, we can follow the [answer of prashant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65160772/11722820):

Open an Anaconda prompt and run:

```
conda init powershell
```

To stop Conda starting by default, run

```
conda config --set auto_activate_base false
```

Answer (score 0):

`& 'C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1'; conda activate 'C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3'`

This is the command found in `Anaconda Powershell Prompt (Miniconda3).lnk` on my computer.

On my machine, I can enter the environment anywhere by executing these two commands.

Answer (score 0):

Using Python3.11 and downloaded 64-bit Windows Miniconda installer.

In the  Anaconda prompt I initially typed in the following command:

```
$ conda init powershell
```

But upon running conda in powershell, I still got the same error.

Resolved it by running `notepad $PROFILE`, when Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 is opened,in which I set manually:

```
# Conda initialize

(& "<path_to_conda_dir>\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1") 
$env:CONDA_EXE = "<path_to_conda_dir>\Scripts\conda.exe"
$env:_CE_M=""
$env:_CE_CONDA=""
$env:CONDA_PYTHON_EXE = "C:\Windows\py.exe"
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('CONDA_EXE', '<path_to_conda_dir>\Scripts\conda.exe', [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('_CE_M', '', [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('_CE_CONDA', '', [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('CONDA_PYTHON_EXE', 'C:\Windows\py.exe', [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
$env:PATH = "<path_to_conda_dir>\condabin;" + $env:PATH
```