# Error when trying to use Conda on Visual Studio Code: "conda : The term 'conda' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda

I am trying to build a basic machine learning algorithm, and to do so I am using the Anaconda interpreter for Python. However, even though Visual Studio Code appears to have recognized Conda as the interpreter, and I have the Anaconda 3 shell working as a separate application, I cannot get Conda to work in Visual Studio Code.

Whenever I try to check for Conda, I get the following error:

```
conda : The term 'conda' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ conda activate base
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (conda:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I have tried the fixes linked here: *['Conda' is not recognized as internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44515769/conda-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command)*

However, they did not work for me. I tried setting Conda to my path, yet I still got the same error.

Comment: Where are you trying to execute that command?

Comment: @Spaceball -Have you tried restarting VSCode after adding the conda system path?

Comment: @AMC I am executing it in powershell in the terminal in vscode, in the path for my project (i.e. C:\Users\User\Documents\Machine-Learning). Is this what you mean?

Comment: @JillCheng I just restarted VSCode and it appears that the issue remains.

Comment: @Spaceball -Could you find the three file locations "Anaconda3", "Anaconda3\Scripts", and "\Library\bin"? And could the conda environment be activated in a powershell terminal outside of VSCode?

Comment: @JillCheng - I could find these file locations in my computer. However, when I try to do anything with conda in the outside PowerShell terminal, I also get the same error.

Comment: @Spaceball  -The content displayed on the terminal means that the terminal cannot find anaconda. Therefore, if the environment variables are configured correctly, it is recommended that you try to reinstall Anaconda.

Comment: It seems like a bug to me if VS Code can locate the anaconda environment in the editor, but when you launch a terminal inside VS Code the environment can't be found.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Run Anaconda/Miniconda
2. Activate the environment there:

```
conda activate your-env
```

3. Start Visual Studio Code from the Anaconda/Miniconda terminal:

```
code
```

[image]

Then Visual Studio Code should recognize `conda`:
[image]

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66670158/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I have provided screenshots of user interface as additional information and I believe it helps. The necessary steps are described in text.

Answer (score 1):

To get Python, Anaconda, and Conda to work well with Visual Studio Code I installed the Python extension.

Then in the Python extension settings, set the `Python: Conda Path` to your `conda.exe` and the 'Python: Default Interpreter Path to your `python.exe`.

For me the `conda.exe` path was in `...\Anaconda3\Library\Scripts\conda.exe` and the 'python.exe`file was the Conda base environment one at`...\Anaconda3\python.exe`.

Comment: I did exactly what you said but the error persisted. any more idea?

Comment: @DavidH.J. What is the path to your conda.exe?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to fix this.

1. (easier) via Anaconda Navigator:

   a) If you have an Anaconda environment already setup. Open Anaconda Navigator → *Home* → *Launch Visual Studio Code*.

   This must get all the Python and [Conda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conda_(package_manager)) executable paths correctly configured for the Visual Studio Code editor.

   b) To verify, install Python Extensions in Visual Studio Code if not yet installed.
   Then go to *[Command Palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)* → *Preferences:Open User Settings* → *Extensions* → *Python*

   c) then search for the *Python:default* interpreter Path.

   [image]

   And *Python:Conda Path*:

   [image]
2. Via Python Extensions in Visual Studio Code

   Follow b) and c) steps from the above 1) approach. Add/Edit both the paths to correct the paths on your machine.