# Basic python commands no longer recognised in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip

Tried to install a python package by typing the following in VS Code's powershell:

```
pip install music21
```

This gives however the notorious error:

```
pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

This did not work either

```
python -m pip install music21
```

Trying to install pip itself produced the same problem:
conda install pip

```
conda : The term 'conda' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65064740/error-when-trying-to-use-conda-on-vs-code-conda-the-term-conda-is-not-recog) other thread the suggestion was to start VS code from inside the activated conda env, which in my case did not work: I still get the same errors.

One problem might be is that although I never intended this, I ended up with many different python installations:

[image]

However, I don't think this is it, as the problem I report happens whichever one of those interpreters I choose.

Am on Windows 10. I used to be able to run pip fine until a few weeks ago when I last used VS Code. Can't think of anything that I expected could have interfered with python envs, or env variables etc

Comment: Which OS are you on? if you're on windows, is Python in your Path? Also, what do you think may have caused this to "no longer" work (presumably it worked before and something changed)?

Comment: apologies, I'll edit my question to fill in these crucial details; in short: Win10, and nothing I can think of

Comment: as for the user variable Path there are indeed python-related paths there. Can't imagine how this would have changed by itself tho.

Comment: Per your answer, flagging to close this as a duplicate of ['Conda' is not recognized as internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44515769/conda-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: Yes, requested the same flag myself.

Comment: Whence the negative comment for my answer, as long as I recognised my mistake and closed the question?....

Comment: @z8080: I didn't downvote you. But the reason is likely because link-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow. See [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) Positively, as mentioned elsewhere, you'll recover the reputation once that answer is deleted (though it'll take upwards of a day for the system to refund them).