# Cannot recognize conda or python in zsh

Tags: python, conda, zsh

I have been attempting to setup my home coding environment to use python inside of vscode on a zsh. I have successfully enabled WSL2, installed Ubuntu, and Anaconda 3, and configured my zsh with oh-my-zsh. An anaconda prompt recognizes python and conda, but I cannot get conda or python to be recognized within my zsh. My Anaconda installation exists in a different area than where my home directory for zsh is located. The two areas can still be navigated between, so I don't think that is an issue. I have attempted:

- Altering my environment variables (Path) to include the locations of both installations. This has not changed anything, despite the new paths clearing appearing in my $PATH.
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wAeI.png
- *conda init zsh*. I have tried this in an anaconda prompt (works but creates and alters files where anaconda thinks the home directory is, not where zsh thinks it is) https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOod2.png, and in a zsh terminal (this produces various errors) https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5dKv.png.
- Taking the conda relevant text from the .zshrc file produced from the *conda init zsh* in the anaconda prompt and adding it to the one I source (again, produces errors) https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzfDc.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZHwF.png
- Altering the default paths in vscode for both python and conda (does not work)
- Launching vscode from anaconda prompt (the paths in the anaconda prompt are not remembered)
- Following instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65064740/error-when-trying-to-use-conda-on-vs-code-conda-the-term-conda-is-not-recog), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44515769/conda-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64149680/how-to-activate-conda-environment-from-powershell) with no success.

At this rate I am truly lost on what I should do. How do I get conda and python to be recognized when I am operating in zsh? This is my *conda info*, if it helps. https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOwmI.png