# Change conda default environment in Windows powershell

Tags: python, powershell, anaconda

I am an `Anaconda` user either if I open the `Powershell` through the `Anaconda Powershell` batch or normally from `Windows`, I got this prompt:

```
(base) PS C:\Users\yt75534>
```

I have upgrade my `Anaconda 64 bit` to `python 3.10` and I activated a new environment named `py310` with:

```
conda create -n py310 python=3.10
```

I wanted to make it my default environment.
I tried to change it through `Anaconda Navigator` but it didn't work, so I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69816297/2562058) guideline.
Now, when I open the `Powershell` through the `Anaconda` batch I got

```
 (py310) PS C:\Users\yt75534>
```

and I am very happy for such an achievement.
But when I open it normally from Windows I got:

```
(base) PS C:\Users\yt75534>
```

I wish that either I open the `Powershell` with `Anaconda` or from `Windows` I got the same `venv`. How to fix it?

Comment: Not a Windows user, but on bash we turn off **base** auto-activation (`conda config --set auto_activate_base false`) and append an activation command for the desired environment, e.g., `echo "conda activate py310" >> ~/.bashrc`. For PowerShell, the .bashrc equivalent is a profile (code that gets run at shell startup). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64149680/how-to-activate-conda-environment-from-powershell) might have relevant info, at least as pertains to manipulating the user PowerShell profile. Just be careful not to overwrite your existing profile.