# I can't seem to install Pytorch through Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, pytorch

I am very new to Python and I'm trying to install Pytorch through Anaconda. I go to Start > Anaconda3 (64-bit) > Anaconda Prompt (anaconda3). I open the prompt and type in the command that I got from the website https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally, the command being, `conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch`, but when I type it in it says

"'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Can someone help me please?

Comment: does this helps you https://anaconda.org/pytorch/pytorch

Comment: It's not pytorch. Something wrong with your Anaconda installation since it doesn't even register `conda` command.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44515769/conda-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command

Comment: try: `source ~/.bashrc` if you are making an ssh connection. and then try `conda instal.....`