# I'm having trouble activating virtual environment using anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

I have installed anaconda 4.11.0 and I'm trying to activate my venv using the `conda activate base` but it shows me this error

```
conda : The term 'conda' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Now, I've added the location of the project to the path, still nothing.

Comment: If you use Linux of Mac check your zsh/bash profile and look if the conda path is found there. I think this happenned ot me once and I had to manually add the conda path for it to be recognized

Comment: If you use windows try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44515769/conda-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command

Comment: I've added the new Path but it still shows the same error