# Why is scikit learn v1.1 not available for me via anaconda distribution

Tags: scikit-learn, conda, anaconda3

For reference I am using conda 22.9.0, Python 3.9.13, scikit-learn 1.0.2 according to conda list and I am using Windows OS 64 bit.

The newest sklearn version it will acknowledge or allow me to have is v1.0.2.

Update: No error is displayed when I try to update via conda update scikit-learn, it simply says "# All requested packages already installed.".

Comment: Please post the error you get when trying to install the latest version.

Comment: @desertnaut I don't get any errors - it just seems to think that 1.0.2 is the latest version

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have it installed or show the error message you get. You might wanna install it via `conda install scikit-learn` in your cmd

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for your help. When I run conda commands in cmd it doesn't recognize the command.

Comment: Looks like your conda is not in your path. Try the first solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44515769/conda-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command