# system() doesn't see PATH variables

Tags: r, unix, anaconda

I'm trying to evoke shell command via my R function. Unfortunatelly shell instance seems not to see PATH and fail.

I used following command to add `conda` to path

```
echo 'export PATH=~/anaconda2/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Unfortuantelly `system("conda help")` retruns that `conda` is not found. Also `system("env | grep PATH")` does not return conda. I would like to emphasize that anaconda reacts properly when I execute `conda` in the terminal. Problem occurs when I try to use R function to call terminal.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Anaconda does not recognize conda command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28612500/why-anaconda-does-not-recognize-conda-command)

Comment: Unix.
But conda do recognize my command. It is bash called from R instance which has problem with recognizing it